# No Application is launching or running

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

when running my project, no application is launching

the logcat says
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

heres my xml code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mangjuam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mangjuam.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="register0"></activity>
        <activity android:name="register1"></activity>
        <activity android:name="register2"></activity>
        <activity android:name="register3"></activity>
        <activity android:name="completeform0"></activity>
        <activity android:name="completeform1"></activity>
        <activity android:name="completeform2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Well you don't have a launcher Activity.

Comment: thank you for your response , is there any missing line of code in my xml? if there is , what should i put it in

Comment: it works now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an intent filter for your main activity, Here is an example of a code that launches MainActivity:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name=".download.DownloadService"/>
    <activity android:name=".download.DownloadActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".details.DetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".list.MoviesActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

As you can see MainActivity has an intent filter that launches it, make sure to add one to your manifest, and if it doesn't work try to rebuild the project aswell.

Comment: it works now thannks

Answer (score 4):

Make an activity as Launcher like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: it works now thannks

Comment: @JosephVincentAlesna as it solves the problem, you might accept the answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

A launcher activity is created like this .

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SpalshActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

change the splashActivity to MainActivity in your case

Comment: it works now thanks